# git clone from within pre-commit hook causes hook to fail

Tags: git

I have a pre-commit hook that needs to run a custom, in-house scanner on all committed files. This scanner is also maintained in its own git repo. So in the hook file I run `git clone ...` to make sure the latest version is being used. The problem I'm running into is that all `git` commands after the clone work on the cloned repo instead of the one for which the hook is running. As a result, I cannot get a list of updated files. Additionally, the hook always fails with:

> error: invalid object...
>   error: Error building trees

Where the invalid object listed is from the cloned repo.

I've made sure I'm cloning into a completely different directory. I've also set the `GIT_TRACE` and `GIT_TRACE_SETUP` environment variables before committing. I can see that the git_dir, worktree and cwd values are all as I would expect them. They are set to the first repo initially, then to the cloned repo during the clone process, then back to the first repo after the clone completes.

As soon as I remove the `git clone` the hook runs without a hitch.

I'm running version 2.11.0 of git.

Why is the clone wreaking so much havoc and how can I prevent that?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: I don't think I ever did. Completely forgot about this question. Sorry.

Comment: It turns out it has to do with `GIT_INDEX_FILE` environment variable that `git` sets when you commit code, getting picked up by the pre-commit hooks that may be cloning repos. My hooks were invoking bash scripts, so in the bash scripts that had any `git clone` commands, I added `unset GIT_INDEX_FILE`  at the start of the script. This mitigated the error for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out it has to do with `GIT_INDEX_FILE` environment variable that `git` sets when you commit code, getting picked up by the pre-commit hooks that may be cloning repos. My hooks were invoking bash scripts, so in the bash scripts that had any `git clone` commands, I added `unset GIT_INDEX_FILE`  at the start of the script. This mitigated the error for me.